# after update of 22.04 Dell Latitude E6530 won't reboot

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 22.04, dell

I updated my Dell e6530 running Xubuntu 22.04 and it wouldn't reboot.  I did a clean install of 22.04.2 and it rebooted fine until I installed the downloaded updates.  I get to the Ubuntu splash screen and the cursor in the upper left hand corner stops blinking and nothing else happens.  I checked for bios updates but mine is current.